# Cast JSON to varchar with Trino

Tags: sql, json, presto, trino, starburst

I'm trying to cast JSON object from table column to varchar with Trino I tried with these docs here but every time throws an error. https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html
If someone can post an example how I can make that it will be great.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`json_format`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_format)/[`json_parse`](https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/json.html#json_parse) to handle json object conversions instead of casting:

```sql
select json_parse('{"property": 1}') objstring_to_json, json_format(json '{"property": 2}') jsonobj_to_string
```

Output:

| objstring_to_json | jsonobj_to_string |
| --- | --- |
| {"property":1} | {"property":2} |

Comment: I had to do the same in AWS Athena, and the `json_format` function works there as well. @Guru thanks!